# Problem indexing LongField from custom FieldBridge

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, field

for a search using lucene, I made a bridge,

```
public class EntityIDFieldBridge implements FieldBridge {
    @Override
    public void set(String name, Object value, Document document, LuceneOptions luceneOptions) {
        BaseEntity baseEntity = (BaseEntity) value;
        if(value !=null){
            Field field = new LongField(name, baseEntity.getId(),Field.Store.NO);
            document.add(field);
        }
    }
}
```

when I search for the value, I dont get the correct documents. when I search term:* I do get the ones that are not null, so I see that its getting indexed.... StringField is working fine. But I think it should be a long field. Any ideas?

Comment: can you provide more context to your question? please refer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a better question. I've tried to provide a answer but will modify once you add more information if it does not solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the little information you provided, I am assuming that you are not trying to get a value whihc is `null`.

[Field Bridge](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.1/reference/en/html/search-mapping-bridge.html) provided more information on what it is, what lucene supports and how it works:

> In Lucene all index fields have to be represented as Strings. For this
>   reason all entity properties annotated with @Field have to be indexed
>   in a String form. For most of your properties, Hibernate Search does
>   the translation job for you thanks to a built-in set of bridges. In
>   some cases, though you need a more fine grain control over the
>   translation process.

Also for Null values

> null elements are not indexed. Lucene does not support null elements
>   and this does not make much sense either.

Comment: You mean to say you cant store a field as a long? The LongField documentation seems to suggest otherwise. It stores it in such a way that it can be used in range searching. What am I missing?

Comment: No I didn't say that, you can do this using fieldbridge and you need to provide more information what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I want to add a field to the document so I can search using it as a search term, including ranged searches. The field is a long. Im trying to create a bridge that can extract a long from an object (BaseEntity) and index it

Comment: @TufinDeveloper and whats the issue when you are doing it using `FieldBridge`

Comment: searching property: 5 is not returning the result when it is a longfield

Comment: @TufinDeveloper so you are just using lucene or using Elasticsearch to search your data